# Why does numbering starts from 0?

Tags: numbering, longtable, enumerate, enumitem

I am confused, I feel I did not do anything wrong but there are columns in my table in which the numbering starts from 0. How can I fix this?
Table output: 
[image: output 1]
[image: output 2] 
This is my code now, with complete preamble

```
% Tipe dokumen adalah report dengan satu kolom. 
% Mengatur setting halaman 
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}



% Hyperlink untuk section, link, citation 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=green,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue
}

% Load konfigurasi LaTeX untuk tipe laporan thesis ITHB
\usepackage{if_ithb}

%---- code for appendix at daftar isi---------
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
    \oldappendix
    \addtocontents{toc} 
    {\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{LAMPIRAN }}
}

% Konfigurasi package lainnya
\usepackage[chapter,Algoritme,ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

% Untuk break algorithm biar ga offside
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
{% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
    \begin{center}
        \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
        \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
        \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
            {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
            \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
            \else % #1 is not \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
            \fi
            \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
        }
    }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
        \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

% Daftar Lampiran
\newcommand\listappendixname{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}}
\makeatother

% Daftar Pseudocode - Algoritme
\makeatletter
\def
\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{ALGORITME} 
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{DAFTAR \uppercase{\ALG@name}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}} 
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off}

\tcbset{colback=white!10!white,colframe=black!50!black, highlight math style= {enhanced,colframe=black,colback=black!10!white,boxsep=0pt}}

% Daftar pemenggalan suku kata dan istilah dalam LaTeX
\include{hype.indonesia}

% Variabel baru untuk menyimpan nomor halaman
\newcounter{originalpagenumber}%
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}%

% Daftar isi, supaya subsubsection terindeks juga
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Set custom font family
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,
}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\setcellgapes{5pt}

\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{
    \fancyhf{} %Clears the header/footer
    \fancyfoot{% Footer
        \makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
            \rlap{\hspace{.75cm}% Push out of margin by \footskip
                \smash{% Remove vertical height
                    \raisebox{4.87in}{% Raise vertically
                        \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
\begin{document}

\begin{small}   
    \begin{longtable}{| p {0.3cm} | p {2.2cm} | p {3cm} | p {3cm} | p {3.5cm} |}
        \caption{\textit{State of the Art}} 
        \label{table:stateOfTheArt}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{No} & \textbf{Peneliti} & \textbf{Judul} & \textbf{Objektif} & \textbf{Hasil} \\    
        \endhead
        
        \hline
        1 & 
        Chitralekha Gupta, Haizhou Liy, and Ye Wang (2017) &
        Perceptual Evaluation of Singing Quality &
        Melakukan evaluasi rekaman penyanyi berdasarkan enam parameter: \textit{pitch, rhythm, voice quality, vibrato, volume, pitch dynamic range}, dan memberikan penilaian atas gabungan parameter tersebut &
        Metode gabungan menghasilkan akurasi sebesar 96\%.\\
        
        \hline
        2 &
        Jong Wook Kim, Justin Salamon, Peter Li, Juan Pablo Bello (2018) &
        CREPE: A Convolutional Representation for Pitch Estimation &
        \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt, 
            before={\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright},
            leftmargin=14pt]
            \item Melakukan estimasi \textit{fundamental frequency} dari \textit{monophonic sound recording}
            \item Membuat algoritme estimasi \textit{pitch} yang berdasarkan pengolahan data
        \end{enumerate}
        & 
        Akurasi dengan metrik RPA dan RCA adalah 99\% dengan dataset RWC-synth, dan dengan \textit{dataset} MedleyDB sebesar 96,7\% untuk metrik RPA dan 97\% untuk metrik RCA\\ 
        
        \hline
        3 &
        Rachel M. Bittner, Brian McFee, Justin Salamon, Peter Li, Juan P. Bello (2017) &
        Deep Salience Representations for F$_0$ Estimation in Polyphonic Music &
        Memberikan pendekatan baru dengan menggunakan metode FCNN untuk mempelajari representasi unik \textit{fundamental frequency} yang dilatih dengan \textit{dataset} besar &
        \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt, 
            before={\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright},
            leftmargin=14pt]
            \item Dengan \textit{dataset} Bach10, menghasilkan akurasi 63\%. 
            \item Dengan \textit{dataset} MedleyDB, menghasilkan akurasi 50\%. 
            \item Dengan \textit{dataset} Su, menghasilkan akurasi 48\%.
        \end{enumerate}\\ 
        
        \hline
        4 &
        Dongmei Wang, Chengzhu Yu, John H. L. Hansen (2017) &
        Robust Harmonic Features for Classification-Based Pitch Estimation &
        Melakukan estimasi \textit{pitch} berdasarkan \textit{robust harmonic features} dengan membuat kandidat \textit{pitch} dan melakukan seleksi target \textit{pitch} &
        Evaluasi menggunakan GPE (Gross Pitch Error). Akurasi pengujian menggunakan Keele sebesar 64,3\%, dan menggunakan CSTR sebesar 52,3\%. \\ 
        \hline  
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

This is `if_ithb` style package

```
% Mengatur bahasa latex
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Untuk pengaturan spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

% Untuk mengatur level section 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

% Digunakan untuk memasukan gambar ke laporan. 
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Untuk mengatur spacing antara paragraf
\usepackage{parskip}

% Membuat indent
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1.5cm}

% Untuk mengkustomisasi margin
\usepackage{scrextend}

% Untuk mengatur header dan footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Membuat seluruh tulisan menjadi Times New Roman. 
\usepackage{pslatex}

% Merubah numbering chapter dan section untuk judul setiap bab menggunakan romawi dan judul anak bab menggunakan arabic
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}\hspace{0,3cm}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}\hspace{-0,35cm}}


% Merubah huruf kapital pada judul daftar isi, daftar gambar, dan daftar table
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{BAB }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries BAB 1 :\ } % if more than 9 chapters, use "Chapter 10"
\cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\mylen}

% Mengatur font section
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

% Untuk merupakan format penulisan BAB
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\doublespacing\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\filcenter}      {0.15cm}{\centering\uppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1cm}{20pt}

% Mengatur spacing section
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
    
% Digunakan untuk mengatur caption dalam dokumen.
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=up]{caption}
% Untuk menghapus titik dua (colon)
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}

% Mengatur nomor caption gambar
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

% Mengatur nomor caption table
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}

% Mengatur Hyphenation pada latex
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

% Untuk mengatur setting indent
\setlength\parindent{1.30cm}

% Untuk memasukkan table
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Untuk mengatur width
\usepackage{changepage}

% Menggatur setting halaman 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=4cm,            % <-- you want to adjust this
  top=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  bottom=3cm,
}

% Teks testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Untuk mengatur subscript supscript
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

% Untuk mengatur wrap picture
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Untuk notasi matematika
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% untuk mengatur label nomor pada rumus
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

% Untuk mengatur spacing daftar gambar
\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}

%untuk mengatur package include table in excel
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% untuk mengatur landscape page
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Comment: This is probably a feature of the `if_ithb` package, the content of which I do not know as it is not present on TeX Live

Comment: I'll post the ```if_ithb``` in a minute now. @Ivan

Comment: @Ivan, please see the edited post.

Comment: Sorry, `if_ithb` has nothing to do with it. Try loading `hyperref` at the end of the preamble o after the other packages.

Comment: There are no effects..

Comment: Your example is humongously too long.  Trim out the parts that don't contribute to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MWE below I have simply 1) replaced `\usepackage{if_ithb}` with the code you provided and 2) moved `hyperef` and its settings just before `\begin{document}`. As you can see the numbering is correct

```
% Tipe dokumen adalah report dengan satu kolom. 
% Mengatur setting halaman 
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
   
% Load konfigurasi LaTeX untuk tipe laporan thesis ITHB
% Mengatur bahasa latex
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Untuk pengaturan spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

% Untuk mengatur level section 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

% Digunakan untuk memasukan gambar ke laporan. 
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Untuk mengatur spacing antara paragraf
\usepackage{parskip}

% Membuat indent
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1.5cm}

% Untuk mengkustomisasi margin
\usepackage{scrextend}

% Untuk mengatur header dan footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Membuat seluruh tulisan menjadi Times New Roman. 
\usepackage{pslatex}

% Merubah numbering chapter dan section untuk judul setiap bab menggunakan romawi dan judul anak bab menggunakan arabic
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}\hspace{0,3cm}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}\hspace{-0,35cm}}


% Merubah huruf kapital pada judul daftar isi, daftar gambar, dan daftar table
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{BAB }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries BAB 1 :\ } % if more than 9 chapters, use "Chapter 10"
\cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\mylen}

% Mengatur font section
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

% Untuk merupakan format penulisan BAB
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\doublespacing\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\filcenter}      {0.15cm}{\centering\uppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1cm}{20pt}

% Mengatur spacing section
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
    
% Digunakan untuk mengatur caption dalam dokumen.
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=up]{caption}
% Untuk menghapus titik dua (colon)
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}

% Mengatur nomor caption gambar
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

% Mengatur nomor caption table
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}

% Mengatur Hyphenation pada latex
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

% Untuk mengatur setting indent
\setlength\parindent{1.30cm}

% Untuk memasukkan table
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Untuk mengatur width
\usepackage{changepage}

% Menggatur setting halaman 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=4cm,            % <-- you want to adjust this
  top=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  bottom=3cm,
}

% Teks testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Untuk mengatur subscript supscript
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

% Untuk mengatur wrap picture
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Untuk notasi matematika
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% untuk mengatur label nomor pada rumus
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

% Untuk mengatur spacing daftar gambar
\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}

%untuk mengatur package include table in excel
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% untuk mengatur landscape page
\usepackage{rotating}


%---- code for appendix at daftar isi---------
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
    \oldappendix
    \addtocontents{toc} 
    {\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{LAMPIRAN }}
}

% Konfigurasi package lainnya
\usepackage[chapter,Algoritme,ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

% Untuk break algorithm biar ga offside
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
{% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
    \begin{center}
        \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
        \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
        \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
            {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
            \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
            \else % #1 is not \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
            \fi
            \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
        }
    }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
        \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

% Daftar Lampiran
\newcommand\listappendixname{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}}
\makeatother

% Daftar Pseudocode - Algoritme
\makeatletter
\def
\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{ALGORITME} 
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{DAFTAR \uppercase{\ALG@name}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}} 
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off}

\tcbset{colback=white!10!white,colframe=black!50!black, highlight math style= {enhanced,colframe=black,colback=black!10!white,boxsep=0pt}}

% Daftar pemenggalan suku kata dan istilah dalam LaTeX
\include{hype.indonesia}

% Variabel baru untuk menyimpan nomor halaman
\newcounter{originalpagenumber}%
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}%

% Daftar isi, supaya subsubsection terindeks juga
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Set custom font family
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,
}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\setcellgapes{5pt}

\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{
    \fancyhf{} %Clears the header/footer
    \fancyfoot{% Footer
        \makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
            \rlap{\hspace{.75cm}% Push out of margin by \footskip
                \smash{% Remove vertical height
                    \raisebox{4.87in}{% Raise vertically
                        \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}

% Hyperlink untuk section, link, citation 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=green,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}   
    \begin{longtable}{| p {0.3cm} | p {2.2cm} | p {3cm} | p {3cm} | p {3.5cm} |}
        \caption{\textit{State of the Art}} 
        \label{table:stateOfTheArt}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{No} & \textbf{Peneliti} & \textbf{Judul} & \textbf{Objektif} & \textbf{Hasil} \\    
        \endhead
        
        \hline
        1 & 
        Chitralekha Gupta, Haizhou Liy, and Ye Wang (2017) &
        Perceptual Evaluation of Singing Quality &
        Melakukan evaluasi rekaman penyanyi berdasarkan enam parameter: \textit{pitch, rhythm, voice quality, vibrato, volume, pitch dynamic range}, dan memberikan penilaian atas gabungan parameter tersebut &
        Metode gabungan menghasilkan akurasi sebesar 96\%.\\
        
        \hline
        2 &
        Jong Wook Kim, Justin Salamon, Peter Li, Juan Pablo Bello (2018) &
        CREPE: A Convolutional Representation for Pitch Estimation &
        \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt, 
            before={\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright},
            leftmargin=14pt]
            \item Melakukan estimasi \textit{fundamental frequency} dari \textit{monophonic sound recording}
            \item Membuat algoritme estimasi \textit{pitch} yang berdasarkan pengolahan data
        \end{enumerate}
        & 
        Akurasi dengan metrik RPA dan RCA adalah 99\% dengan dataset RWC-synth, dan dengan \textit{dataset} MedleyDB sebesar 96,7\% untuk metrik RPA dan 97\% untuk metrik RCA\\ 
        
        \hline
        3 &
        Rachel M. Bittner, Brian McFee, Justin Salamon, Peter Li, Juan P. Bello (2017) &
        Deep Salience Representations for F$_0$ Estimation in Polyphonic Music &
        Memberikan pendekatan baru dengan menggunakan metode FCNN untuk mempelajari representasi unik \textit{fundamental frequency} yang dilatih dengan \textit{dataset} besar &
        \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt, 
            before={\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright},
            leftmargin=14pt]
            \item Dengan \textit{dataset} Bach10, menghasilkan akurasi 63\%. 
            \item Dengan \textit{dataset} MedleyDB, menghasilkan akurasi 50\%. 
            \item Dengan \textit{dataset} Su, menghasilkan akurasi 48\%.
        \end{enumerate}\\ 
        
        \hline
        4 &
        Dongmei Wang, Chengzhu Yu, John H. L. Hansen (2017) &
        Robust Harmonic Features for Classification-Based Pitch Estimation &
        Melakukan estimasi \textit{pitch} berdasarkan \textit{robust harmonic features} dengan membuat kandidat \textit{pitch} dan melakukan seleksi target \textit{pitch} &
        Evaluasi menggunakan GPE (Gross Pitch Error). Akurasi pengujian menggunakan Keele sebesar 64,3\%, dan menggunakan CSTR sebesar 52,3\%. \\ 
        \hline  
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, this is worked. Yesterday, I wrongly moved the ```hyperref``` package. Thank you for the solution. Package ```if_ithb``` is still ```\usepackage{if_ithb}``` and it still works.